# Owin startup bug with Umbraco Cloud - netStandard reference missing

Tags: owin, umbraco7, .net-standard, hangfire, umbraco-cloud

In our current **Umbraco Cloud** project, we are using the **Hangfire** library (1.6.17) - the lib has a **OWIN** dependency (1.0.0).

Here is the code to call the hangfire launch:

In our current project, we are using the Hangfire library (1.6.17) - the lib has a OWIN dependency (1.0.0).

Here is the code to call the hangfire launch:

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;
using Umbraco.Web;
using Hangfire;
using Hangfire.Dashboard;
using Hangfire.Annotations;
using Umbraco.Core.Models;
using Umbraco.Core;
using System.Web;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(XX.Web.Core.Startup))]
namespace XX.Web.Core
{
    public class Startup : UmbracoDefaultOwinStartup
    {
        public override void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            //ensure the default options are configured
            base.Configuration(app);

            var cs = Umbraco.Core.ApplicationContext.Current.DatabaseContext.ConnectionString;

            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage(cs);

            app.UseHangfireDashboard("/umbraco/backoffice/hangfire", new DashboardOptions
            {
                Authorization = new[] { new UmbracoUserAuthorisedFilter() },
                AppPath = "/Umbraco"
            });

            app.UseHangfireServer();
        }
    }

    public class UmbracoUserAuthorisedFilter : IDashboardAuthorizationFilter
    {
        public bool Authorize([NotNull] DashboardContext context)
        {
            // In case you need an OWIN context, use the next line,
            // `OwinContext` class is the part of the `Microsoft.Owin` package.
            //var context = new OwinContext(owinEnvironment);

            // Allow all authenticated users to see the Dashboard (potentially dangerous).
            //return context.Authentication.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;

            //this if you want to lock down to admins only
            var userService = ApplicationContext.Current.Services.UserService;
            var user = userService.GetByUsername(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);

            return user.IsAdmin();
            //this if you just want to make sure user is logged into backoffice
            //return UmbracoContext.Current.Security.CurrentUser != null;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the default hangfire startup code to be able to use the library. The code has been working fine on 2 local machines, one Azure Web App instance but when I push this code to the Umbraco Cloud branch I get the following error:

Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

The issue is: we are not using .net standard, both projects (web and core) are using .net framework 4.6.2

Is there any workaround for that issue ?

[image]